# How to get comma separated values from List of Maps in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have listMap1 variable of type List[Map [String, String]] and I want all values associated with key 'k1' as one string with comma separated values

```
import fiddle.Fiddle, Fiddle.println
import scalajs.js

@js.annotation.JSExport
object ScalaFiddle {

  var m1:Map[String,String] = Map(("k1"->"v1"), ("k2"->"vv1")) 
  var m2:Map[String,String] = Map(("k1"->"v2"),("k2"->"vv2"))
  var m3:Map[String,String] = Map(("k1"->"v3"),("k2"->"vv3"))

  var listMap1 = List(m1,m2,m3)
  var valList = ??  // need all values assoicated with k1 like -->  v1,v2,v3...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach would be:

```
listMap1.flatMap(_.get("k1")).mkString(",")
```

be warned that this will not work if you're generating CSV data and the associated values contain `,`s e.g. `Map(("k1" -> "\some, string"))`

Comment: @Pavel - I would guess `flatMap` is quicker since it only requires a single key lookup and only creates one intermediate list instead of two.

Comment: There is also the old standby for better performance, avoiding any intermediate lists at all: `listMap1.iterator.flatMap(_.get("k1").iterator).mkString(",")`.

Answer (score 1):

is that ok ??

```
  val r = listMap1.filter(l => l.contains("k1") ).map(r => r("k1") ).mkString(",")
```

Comment: Or perhaps the shorter form with `_`: `listMap1.filter(_.contains("k1") ).map(_("k1") ).mkString(",")`.

Comment: Strongly suspect that flatMap solution faster :)) filter operation is extra O(n)? effort in this specific case.

Comment: You can always use a view to avoid intermediate collection allocation.